# Declaring a function as inline friend in different namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a class declared like this :

```
namespace nsp1
{

 class A
 {
  public :
   inline friend void DoSomething();

  private :
   A();

   int a;
 };

}
```

Like this, the function `DoSomething()` will be in the namespace nsp1.
Is there a way to declare this function to have it both inline friend and outside of the namespace?

Comment: `DoSomething()` is not taking any argument of type `A`, then what is the point of making it `friend` of `A`? I'm wondering!

Comment: @Nawaz The DoSomething() creates the static object of type A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
 namespace nsp1
{
    class A;
}

inline void DoSomething(const nsp1::A & a);
 namespace nsp1
{

 class A
 {
  public :
   inline friend void ::DoSomething(const nsp1::A & a);

  private :
   A();

   int a;
 };

}

inline void DoSomething(const nsp1::A & a)
{
     std::cout<<a.a<<std::endl;//a.a is private!
}
```

Comment: doh forward declaration. Completely forgot. Thanks

Comment: Try taking an argument of type `A` that DoSomething() may operate on. Means, solve this for function `DoSomething(A &a)`.

Comment: @Nawaz Well nsp1::A have private constructor, so only DoSomething can build nsp1::A objects. So I change function DoSomething and now it is calling  nsp1::A 's constructor.

Comment: that is not what I said. I specifically said `DoSomething(A &a)` which is slightly different than the original function! So try using this signature instead of the original one!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do it in one go. You first need to declare the namespace and function, then define the class which befriends the function, and then define the function.

```
namespace nsp2
{
   void DoSomething();
}

namespace nsp1
{
   class A
   {
   public :
      friend void nsp2::DoSomething();

   private :
      A();

      int a;
   };
}

namespace nsp2
{
   inline void DoSomething()
   {
      nsp1::A a;
      a.a = 42;
   }
}
```